# Efficient and comfortable mod_security monitoring with sentry.io or similar tools?

Tags: mod-security

When using `mod_security` one might drown in error reports.

sentry is a comfortable tool to monitor software errors, sort them, ignore unimportant ones and so on.

I was wondering if it is possible to connect `mod_security` with sentry.io?

The only project I found is https://github.com/iboware/modsecurity-sentry but it does not not even have a readme :-)

Another option might be to use logstash and https://github.com/javiermatos/logstash-output-sentry

Comment: iboware/modsecurity-sentry does not look very big. you might be able to use it without readme and make a PR

Comment: Time to learn go

Comment: Requests for product, service, or learning material recommendations are off-topic because they attract low quality, opinionated and spam answers, and the answers become obsolete quickly. Instead, describe the business problem you are working on, the research you have done, and the steps taken so far to solve it.

Comment: Okay, I will try to improve the question.